# How can I get a translucent and colorized image in Android like the new Google Play Newsstand header?

Tags: java, android, image-processing, transparency, translucency

I'm trying to get a translucent and colorized image like the new Google Play Newsstand app, but everything which I tried until this moment doesn't work perfectly. What I mean is more specified by the images below.

The Google Play Newsstand header looks like this:

[image]

But my code make up a header to me which looks like this:

[image]

and it's awful!

My code is:

`ImageUtils.getImageFiltered(this, R.drawable.disaster, R.color.transparent_teal)`

In "ImageUtils" class, the method `getImageFiltered(...)` is:

```
public static Drawable getImageFiltered(Context context, int res, int color) {
    Drawable drawable = createContrast(context, res, 50);
    color = context.getResources().getColor(color);
    ColorFilter filter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
    drawable.setColorFilter(filter);
    return drawable;
}
```

The method `createContrast(context, res, 50);` just change the image to black and white.

So, anyone knows how to get a image like the Google's app?

Thanks very much and I'm sorry for my English, I'm just learning yet.

Comment: You should tag with the language you're using - that way it's more likely to be seen by people who can help.

Comment: @JamesWaddington - I've retagged the post and embedded the images to improve the post.

Comment: Thanks @JamesWaddington. I didn't add the images because I can't yet. I'm new on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the createContrast() function, which is over-brightening the lighter shades of grey. You could try fixing that to return a desaturated greyscale image without any contrast adjustment applied, using a ColorMatrix with setSaturation(0) applied. Then apply PorterDuff.

Alternatively you could create the effect using a ColorMatrixColorFilter, created by concatenating a ColorMatrix to convert to greyscale and another to modulate by the color, like this:

```
public static Drawable getImageFiltered(Context context, int res, int color) {
    // load image:
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), res);
    BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);

    // create matrix to convert to greyscale:
    ColorMatrix greyscaleMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
    greyscaleMatrix.setSaturation(0);

    // create matrix to colorize and apply transluceny:
    ColorMatrix colorizeMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
    color = context.getResources().getColor(color);
    colorizeMatrix.setScale(Color.red(color) / 255.0f,
            Color.green(color) / 255.0f,
            Color.blue(color) / 255.0f,
            Color.alpha(color) / 255.0f); // <- try setting this to 1.0f for no translucency

    // concatenate the two matrices and create a ColorMatrixColorFilter from the result:
    greyscaleMatrix.postConcat(colorizeMatrix);
    ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(greyscaleMatrix);

    // apply the filter:
    drawable.setColorFilter(filter);
    return drawable;
}
```

Also it is necessary to make the image translucent? There doesn't seem to be anything showing through from behind it other than a black background.

Comment: Guy, you were right and your solution was the best. I should say that my app header is so beautiful than the Google app header (in my opinion) HAHAHAHA. Thank you very much. You saved my day.

Comment: Hi, @samgak. What if I want a gradient translucent brackground? I've tried [GradientDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html), but I did not get any success. Could you help me on this?

Comment: Hi @AthusVieira, I think it's probably best to ask a new question for that